# Hardhat error installing nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle

Tags: hardhat

```
npm install -D @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: ethers@6.9.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ethers
npm ERR!   peer ethers@"6.x" from @typechain/ethers-v6@0.5.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typechain/ethers-v6
npm ERR!     peer @typechain/ethers-v6@"^0.5.1" from @typechain/hardhat@9.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@typechain/hardhat
npm ERR!       @typechain/hardhat@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer ethers@"^6.1.0" from @typechain/hardhat@9.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typechain/hardhat
npm ERR!     @typechain/hardhat@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: ethers@5.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ethers
npm ERR!   peer ethers@"^5.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
npm ERR!     dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/lokicheck/.npm/_logs/2024-01-10T14_58_51_279Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/lokicheck/.npm/_logs/2024-01-10T14_58_51_279Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: I've got the same thing, have you found a solution yet?
I believe it has something to do with the dependencies but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do check out my latest answer, and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

I removed the node modules, and use yarn instead, then followed the instructions of "npm install *dependencies*" from the terminal. The problem will be fixed.